# background image filling full screen not just body

Tags: html, css, image, background

My background image should just fill the body element but it's taking up the entire viewport.  I've edited my original post to get rid of extraneous code.  I hope what I've posted here is sufficient but not too much.  Basically what's happening is that the background color of the html is filling up the screen and the background image in the body is not showing.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
html {background: #95A3C2;}
body {
background-image: url(_images/pg_p_lewis_bckgrnd.jpg);
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto 0;
font-size: 1.1em;
line-height: 1.3em;
font-family: "minion-pro";
}

<body>
<div id="main">
<div class="text">
<p>text</p>
</div>
<div class="image">
<p>Image Gallery</p>
<p><span class="caption">Center image vertically on page and hover to enlarge.</span></p>
<p><img class="img-zoom" src="_images/RL_LEWIS_Alex_KCC_1197_Sur_1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land grant" width="259" height="387"></p>
</div>
</div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>  
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.img-zoom').hover(function() {
$(this).addClass('transition');

    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('transition');
    });
  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have so much code that it is incredibly difficult to tell what you are trying to do. Ideally your question should have more non-code than code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: background-size? why u didn't input background-size in your body?

Comment: I tried adding a background-size but I have the same problem - the html color shows up for the entire screen and the background image does not show in the body.

Answer (score 1):

Your background image is filling the entire viewport because the `<body>` element is weird like that. If no background is set on the `<html>` element, the background will fill the entire viewport.

Without setting the background property of the `<html>` property:

```css
body {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<p>Text</p>
```

Setting the background property of the `<html>` element.

```css
body {
  background: #f00;
}
html {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>Text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks.  But if you add a color like you did here to the html that color shows for the entire screen including in the body and the background image is not showing in the body at all.

Comment: @BartonLewis if you can provide a *simple* example showing that I might be able to help, I can't seem to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I pared down what is on my actual page but it's difficult to know how much to omit since I don't know if it's the structure of my html or some other reason that is making the background color override the background image. The image is in a different folder than the html but since the css is in the document, not an external style sheet, I don't think that is the issue.  Sorry if this is not what you need and thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I added a section tag to enclose my div's and now the background image is showing and the background color for the html is where it should be.  Not sure why that worked but it did.